Directory Connector CLI (bwdc) Bitwarden: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'directorySettings')
Проблема возникает в bwdc (Directory Connector CLI) Bitwarden.
Делал настройку по офф документации, Bitwarden поднят на собственном сервере, все настройки правильные, авторизация в CLI проходит, но нужно настроить интеграцию с AD/LDAP, такая функция есть, при вводе команды bwdc config directory 0 которая должна назначить источник интеграции Active Directory/LDAP возникает ошибка:

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'directorySettings')

эта же ошибка возникает при выборе любого источника.
Не могу найти решение проблемы, помогите кто сталкивался.
вот дебаг ошибки

root@srv-bitwarden:/home/super# bwdc config directory 0
Initializing lowdb storage service.
db file "/root/.config/Bitwarden Directory Connector/data.json already exists"; using existing db
acquiring db file lock
Attempting to create lowdb storage adapter.
Successfully created lowdb storage adapter.
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
acquiring db file lock
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'directorySettings')```

